# emit ampersand to html page in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-entities

I want to emit an '&' without the '`&amp;`' on the page

document.write('&');

emits `&amp;`

document.write('\&');

emits  `&amp;`

Proof in the generated html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>


    <title></title>
</head><body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.write('&');
    document.write('\&');

</script><div firebugversion="1.5.4" style="display: none;" id="_firebugConsole"></div>&amp;&amp;
</body></html>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Ampersands are only used for escape sequences in HTML. Emitting only & doesn't make sense.

Comment: out of curiosity can i ask why you'd like to do that?

Comment: document.write('&#38;');

Comment: Since & is an escape character in HTML, &amp; is the HTML way to show a &, just like &lt; and &gt; is used to show < and >.

Comment: im building a url string for a link  you know.... ?this=1&that=2 and then writing it to a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wcpro: *"im trying to emit a url on the page ?this=1&that=2, you are telling me that this is not possible?"*

Well, technically the ampersand should be encoded as &amp; in your html-code:

```
<a href="somewhere?this=1&amp;that=2>something</a>
```

When your browser reads the page it decodes &amp; to & and that's what you get when you click on the link.

But what about a single ampersand then?

```
<a href="somewhere?this=1&that=2>something</a>
```

It's wrong, and not legal html. It works because this mistake was so very common that the browsers correct it for you. Just like they try to correct other things like missing tags and all other bad things with the tag-soup.

[W3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2) suggests the use of semicolon instead of ampersand to get rid of this problem.

If you ever try XHTML you will be notified of every single error.

Comment: Technically, [it’s not necessary](http://mothereff.in/ampersands#somewhere%3Fthis%3D1%26that%3D2) to [encode the ampersand in this exact case](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands) as per HTML5 — but it’s definitely safest to encode ampersands at all times.

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done.  Drop this on your page:

```
<span id="and">&</span>
```

and call `alert(document.getElementById("and").innerHTML)`

You'll see &amp;  Your browser is automatically converting & to &amp; when it isn't a valid escape sequence.

Comment: im trying to emit a url on the page ?this=1&that=2, you are telling me that this is not possible?

Comment: Of course you can emit an ampersand on a web page.  Look, I'll do it now - &.  See?  But in HTML ampersand is a special character, so to represent it, you use `&amp;`.  You can't have an ampersand all by itself in the html.  Of course, we do it all the time when we hand-code the html in notepad, but as my answer above demonstrates, the browser is smart enough to convert our invalid html into valid html.  Try running it through <http://validator.w3.org>.

Comment: Why do you want the _source_ to have an &?  Don't you just care about what is displayed in the browser?